# Marck onclick maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem when I click on a Marker,if I do not put the function OnMapclick , the itinerary icon appears and the title

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {


    mMap = googleMap;

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);

    }
```

but if I put it all in the function OnMapClick , the itinerary icon doesn't  appear and the title , I have to work with this function

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);

    } 
                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, arg0.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make your `OnMarkerClickListener.onMarkerClick` method return false:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
        // ... do your stuff

        return false;
    }
});
```

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener):

> public abstract boolean **onMarkerClick** (Marker marker)
>
> //...
>
> **Returns**
>
> true if the listener has consumed the event (i.e., the default behavior should not occur), false otherwise (i.e., the default behavior should occur). The default behavior is for the camera to move to the marker and an info window to appear.